# Magnetic monopole and electromagnetic field quantization procedure

Tags: research-level, quantum-electrodynamics, quantization, magnetic-monopoles

From the Maxwell's equations point of view, existence of magnetic monopole leads to unsuitability of the introduction of vector potential as $\vec B = \operatorname{rot}\vec A$. As a result, it was introducted by Dirac fiber-like theory of monopole, which is considers a model of monopole as the open end of a semi-infinite solenoid. This is physically unsatisfactory. Another approach, is the introduction of another 4-potential along with $A_{\mu},(\text{where  } \mu = 0,1,2,3)$. But such models had problems with formulating in a frame of the principle of least action. And if I'm not mistaken, this problem had been solved (see [Magnetic monopoles and Lorentz force](http://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0203043)). A two-potential models, seems to be more acceptable.

How will the quantization procedure of the electromagnetic field change in two-potential models? Does the photon acquire an additional degree of freedom?

Comment: Particles, which has a fiber-like structure around, like Dirac's monopole, I meant physical usatisfactory.

Comment: A two potential models, I seem to be more acceptable.

Comment: See also "[What is the action for an electromagnetic field if including magnetic charge?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/59874)"

Comment: Does the following [article](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1981PhRvD..24..999K) bear any relevance to your question?

Comment: The essays for finding the monopole are on scene. If it exist it should be somewhere in the highest energies in LHC wich is the same as somewhen at the very begining of the universe