# Lagrangian density of a free electromagnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, gauge-theory, variational-principle

How do you derive the result for the lagrangian density of a free electromagnetic field

Comment: You write down the most general Lagrangian obeying the right symmetries. Then you remove the interaction terms.

Comment: Lagrangian of free electromagnetic field cannot be derived, it can be deduced by symmetric arguments & invariant properties. See 2-nd volume of Ladau course, paragra 27 ("Action for electromagnetic field")

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/55291/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0):

We have following arguments:

- Lagrangian cannot contain potential because they are not defined uniqely due to gauge invariance
- The action should be scalar

These arguments give structure
$$S=a\int dtd^3x\,F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu},$$
where $F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}=2({\bf H}^2-{\bf E}^2)$. Electric field contains term $\partial{\bf A}/\partial t$. The term $(\partial{\bf A}/\partial t)^2$ should appears in $S$ with sign "+". If not, for enough fast variation of ${\bf A}$ action $S$ becomes infinite and has not minimum. So, the constant $a$ should be negative. Finally,
$$S=-a\int dtd^3x\,F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}.$$