# Symmetry breaking, gauge invariance and superconductivity

Tags: symmetry, gauge-theory, definition, gauge-invariance

I still have some confusions over symmetry breaking in superconductivity.

To begin with it’s clear gauge symmetry can’t be spontaneously broken, since it’s not a symmetry to begin with. I want to understand :

(1) Can global, physical $U(1)$ symmetry be spontaneously broken? This seems to be clearly true, and is what happens in superconductivity. There is even no gauge invariance yet without coupling to gauge fields, so SSB works as usual.

The confusion is if one then couples the charged, SSB system to a classical, external gauge field, the system then has gauge invariance.

Is it true then: there are now degenerate groundstates which transform among each other under global $U(1)$, but each is invariant under gauge transformations?

As an example, in the paper by[Greiter](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0503400), he claims, for a BCS groundstate,
\begin{equation}
\lvert\psi_\phi\rangle=\prod_{k}u_k+v_ke^{i\phi}c^\dagger_{k\uparrow}c^\dagger_{-k\downarrow}\lvert 0\rangle
\end{equation}
under a $U(1)$ gauge transformation, both the operators and the state "label" must tranform  simultaneously
\begin{align}
 &c^\dagger_{k\sigma} \rightarrow e^{i\theta} c^\dagger_{k\sigma} \\
&\phi \rightarrow \phi-2\theta
\end{align}
and thus the state is an invariant singlet under "gauge" transformation.

However, under a physical transformation, only the phase $\phi$ transforms, and thus the BCS state is not invariant under a physical transformation, and hence a symmetry broken state.

(2) If the above picture is true, the local order parameter, the Cooper pair condensate, is gauge covariant, how can it be non-vanishing when there is a gauge field? Is it related to the fact the gauge field here is classical?

(3) Finally, what about with dynamical gauge fields, as in Higgs mechanism?

Is there any distinction between a global physical symmetry and a global gauge one? If so,  the gauge symmetry can’t undergo SSB, but can the global symmetry?

If the global symmetry undergo SSB, there are degenerate goundatate(in thermodynamic limit ofc). However, In the notes by [de Wit](https://cds.cern.ch/record/292286/files/B00008237.pdf), he states in sec 12, there is no groundstate degeracy in a gauge theory, which is also a fact stated by t'Hooft that the groundstate must be unique. How does this reconcile with the picture  of condensed matter physicists, that the "global" symmetry is spontaneously broken?

In QFT, however, the gauge fields are dynamical, and there is an integral over all gauge orbits, which then forces an operator like Cooper pair to vanish. Then is the magnitude of Cooper/Higgs field $\langle\lvert\phi\rvert\rangle$ a good order parameter?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13870/50583, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/257018/50583 and their linked questions

Comment: @ACuriousMind thanks for the suggestions. However, I do not find them addressing the global part of the gauge transformations directly/explicitly.

Comment: If a transformation parameter/angle is spacetime independent, then the symmetry is global; global and local (=qauge) are mutually exclusive. In the former case, vector fields are not gauge ones. Where did you see your oxymoronic term?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Why would gauge transformation be local only? Nothing stops a gauge transformation to act the same on all points of spacetime.

Comment: Nothing indeed. When that happens, derivatives of the transformation parameters vanish, and gauge fields transform like plain matter vector fields so the transformation devolves to a global one. It's a name. A frozen liquid is a solid.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Yet I expect there shall still be some difference between a global, physical symmetry and a global gauge transformation. Since the former may effect a transformation between different states, say 2 different configurations of EM fields,  while the latter merely a change of description, say of the 4 potential .

Comment: Think about it and sharpen your query.

Comment: I might be repeating stuff you already know, but a gauge symmetry is a redundancy in the mathematical description of a system. For example, the potential $U(z)=mgz$ is invariant under adding a constant. This is because we can't measure the potential directly, only potential differences or the derivative of the potential. The mathematical description allows for an irrelevant degree of freedom and a gauge transformation changes that irrelevant degree of freedom. A physical symmetry corresponds to actual changes you perform on the system, but still leave it invariant. I hope that answers (1)

Comment: To answer (1) more directly: to have a gauge transformation, we need to change both the phase and the creation operators like you mention. If we only change the phase, we don't have a gauge transformation. They are separate transformations, so you should not expect the system to stay invariant under just a phase transformation.

Comment: My answer here may be relevant: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/528307/

Comment: @CosmasZachos discrete gauge symmetries are spacetime independent, yet they are gauge symmetries.

Comment: "I wish I owned half of that dog."   "Why?" somebody asked.  "Because I would kill my half."