# Classical field theory with fields on different base spaces

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, topology, classical-field-theory, point-particles

Keeping things at a "basic level", a field is a function from a base manifold (of dimension $D4) to some other space. Usually, the [base space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_bundle) is the spacetime but it may be something different (a lattice, etc etc).

For example, it's simple to construct the classical action of a complex scalar field over the usual 3+1 spacetime. Imagine now that we want to let this field interact with a classical membrane, or a string-like object, or a point particle immersed in spacetime. How to write the action for such a theory in which a "low dimensional field" (zero-dimensional in the case of the particle) is immersed into spacetime?  The situation is not conceptually different from when we write the action for a charged particle immersed in a background electromagnetic field. How to generalise the theory (the variational principle) in such a way as to have the coupled equations of motion for the particle and the field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP's scenario is often the case. Perhaps an example is in order. The E&M gauge fields $$A_0,A_1,A_2,A_3:[t_i,t_f]\times \mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}$$
(whose base manifold is spacetime) and $N$ (non-relativistic) point charges $q_1,\ldots, q_N$ with positions
$${\bf r}_1, \ldots, {\bf r}_N: [t_i,t_f]\to \mathbb{R}^3$$
(whose base manifold is a worldline)
are described by the action
$$S[A_0,A_1,A_2,A_3,{\bf r}_1, \ldots, {\bf r}_N]~=~\int \! dt ~L,$$
with Lagrangian
$$\begin{align} L~=~&\sum_{i=1}^N\left( \frac{m_i}{2}{\bf v}^2_i + q_i\{A_0({\bf r}_i) + {\bf v}_i\cdot {\bf A}({\bf r}_i)\} \right)\cr 
~-~&\frac{1}{4} \int d^3 {\bf x}\sum_{\mu,\nu=0}^3F_{\mu\nu}(t,{\bf x})F^{\mu\nu}(t,{\bf x}) \end{align} $$
[in $(-,+,+,+)$ Minkowski sign convention].

Comment: Another example but for particles in GR: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/733858/226902

Comment: $\uparrow$ Indeed.