# Can you write and solve the EM field Lagrangian density without reference to the EM potential?

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, potential, maxwell-equations, variational-principle

Is it possible to write the Lagrangian density for the EM field and charges
$$L=-\frac{1}{4\mu_0}F^{\mu \nu}F_{\mu \nu}+j^{\mu}A_{\mu}$$
only in terms of the Electromagnetic Tensor and current vector? Can you also solve the Euler-Lagrange equation without reference to the potential? For example, witht the Lagrangian density for empty space:
$$L=-\frac{1}{4\mu_0}F^{\mu \nu}F_{\mu \nu}$$
There are no derivatives of $F^{\mu \nu}$, so I don't see how you could derive the field equations from it.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/53018/2451 and links therein.

Comment: By going through the answers to the linked question it is clear that Occam's razor must be applied. This is a dead end street.

Answer (score 0):

The field strength (Faraday Tensor) is defined as:

$$F_{μν}= \partial_{μ}Α_{ν} - \partial_{ν} Α_{μ}$$

You have to vary with respect to the electromagnetic $U(1)$ field $A_{μ}$ everywhere it appears.

Comment: This does not address the question.

Comment: I think it does. The field one varies with respect to is the $A_{\mu}$ which is incorporated in the electromagnetic tensor, which is what i think the OP forgot.

Comment: No, the OP did not forget this.