# Can we measure an electromagnetic field?

Tags: experimental-physics, gauge-theory, measurements, classical-electrodynamics

As far as I can check, the Aharonov-Bohm effect is not -- contrary to what is claimed in the historical paper -- a demonstration that the vector potential $A$ has an intrinsic existence in quantum mechanics, neither that the magnetic field $B$ has an intrinsic existence in classical mechanics, but rather that the *magnetic flux* is the relevant, measurable quantity. Indeed, the phase difference is either $\int A \cdot d\ell$ or $\int B \cdot dS$ (in obvious notations with surface $dS$ and line $d\ell$ infinitesimal elements), and these two quantities are always equal, thanks to the theorem by Stokes.

Then, one could argue that classically one can measure the flux as defined above, whereas in QM one has only the *Wilson loop* $\exp \left[\mathbf{i} \int A \cdot d\ell / \Phi_{0}\right]$, with $\Phi_{0}$ the flux quantum, as a relevant, measurable quantity.

*I just elaborated above about the Aharonov-Bohm effect since it was the first time I realised the possible experimental difference between measuring a flux and a field. Let me now ask my question.*

My question is pretty simple I believe: **Does anyone know a classical experiment measuring the magnetic field $B$ and not the flux $\int B \cdot dS$ ?**
As long as we use circuits the answer is obvious, since one can only have an access to the flux and the voltage drop $\int E \cdot d\ell$ ($E$ the electric field), but do you know other experiment(s)?

As an extra, I believe the same problem arises with force: **Does anyone know a classical experiment probing the force field $F$, and not the work $\int F \cdot d\ell$ ? **

**NB:** The question does not rely on how smart you can be to find a protocol that gives you an *approximate local value of the field*, say $\int F \left(x \right) \cdot d\ell \rightarrow F\left(x_{0} \right)$ with $x_{0}$ a (space-time) position. Instead, one wants to know whether or not a classical measurement can *a priori* gives a local value of the field, without *a posteriori* protocol. Say differently, one wants to know how to interpret a classical measure: is it (always ?) an integral or can it -- under specific conditions -- give a local value ?

*Post-Scriptum:* As an aside, I would like to know if there is some people already pointing this question out (wether it's the flux or the local magnetic field or vector potential that one can measure), and if it exists some reference about that in the literature.

Comment: I must be missing the point, because this seems obvious to me. A bathroom scale is a classical device that measures force, not work. A Hall effect sensor is a classical device that measures B, not flux.

Comment: @BenCrowell As far as I can see, a bathroom scale is the measure of the work of the force done on some spring, so it is not the measure of a force, it is integrated over space. Say differently, your weight is converted to some displacements that you can read / measure. As for the Hall bar measurement, it is clearly an integrated measure over the trajectory of the classical electron, but I've difficulty to relate this to either the flux or some electric work.

Comment: Re classical force: even if I measure it by measuring the acceleration of a test particle, I still have to make a real measurement over a distance.  Since force is a dynamical quantity, something has to *change*.  The scale, where you read the pointer when equilibrium is reached, is just saying that two forces are *equal*.  There still has to be some dynamical measurement somewhere along the chain of design and production when the balance was callibrated.

Comment: @twistor59 Thanks a lot for this enlightening comment. It enforces my idea. Do you have any comment about the measurement of the deviation of a charge under a magnetic field, like in Hall effect, or perhaps easier, like in the cyclotron accelerator ? Thanks again.

Comment: I guess that we measure a force field at a point by calculating particle accelerations from measurements over finite distances and interpret the value of the field at the point as a limit as the distances tend to zero.  In a similar way, in reality we can't grab an "infinitesimally thin" single B field line, we have to grab a bunch of them to make measurements, and interpret the B field as a limit, hence flux sort of creeps into the picture for practical reasons.

Comment: @twistor59 Thanks again. I totally agree with you. I also believe this is a deep drawback of the classical theory. Somehow, one can not discuss classical physics without *interpreting* it the way you did, the same way as we do for quantum mechanics. I believe this point is almost never discussed, and would be highly profitable for students. Also, if one accept our point of view, I believe the polemics about the Aharonov-Bohm effect (whether $A$ or $B$ is the more physical field) would end up, too. Thanks again for sharing your ideas with us.

Comment: All I'm really saying is that classical things like $\bf{B}$ fields are elements of a *model*, hence are idealizations, and can only be approximated by measurements.  I'm not familiar with the arguments for and against, but I have the impression that the AB effect is about a much deeper nonlocality than that caused by the fact that practical experiments inevitably involve some spatial smearing.

Comment: @twistor59 There are indeed two different, subtly related interpretations of the AB effect. One is saying that the $A$ is more important than the $B$ field when discussing quantum mechanics. The second one is about the *non-local* interpretation (to be taken with care each time it is about non-locality of course): the electrons seem to feel the magnetic field even at some place where there is no $B$. My argument goes over both arguments, saying the electrons feel the magnetic flux only.

Comment: There is still the question of how the electrons feel a magnetic flux when there is no magnetic flux intersecting their trajectory. This is what makes the AB effect "non-local", whether you think that the potential, field or flux is the fundamental quantity. In my view, neither of these quantities can be considered fundamental in the AB setup, since they appear as classical constraints rather than dynamical degrees of freedom. Yet the EM field is quantum, not classical. I believe that a first step towards a resolution of this problem was taken in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.6169).

Comment: @Mark Yes, there are still things to understand, and the reference you give is to be understood, too :-). I've seen your question related to it (here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/56926/), and I'm wondering about what Vaidman tried to do. I'll try to answer (if I got an idea of course ;-) on your question. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: All measurements of all physical properties  involve change and work. Therein lies the classical measurement problem. or the classical measurement uncertainty. by decreasing the amount of work required to make a measurement you find noise to be a problem.  By integrating over time, by measuring repeatedly your signal to noise improves.  We are now entering into the world of Claude Shannon.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest device to measure magnetic fields (and not integrated magnetic flux) is an electron. The spin-up/-down energy splitting in a magnetic field is  $g_S\mu_B B$ where $g_S \mu_B \sim 2.8~\mbox{MHz/G}$. This can be measured in a beam machine. The next simplest is the Zeeman splitting of atomic energy levels.  The latter forms the basis of some of the most sensitive magnetometers, for example John Kitching's microfabricated gas cell magnetometers [(external link to a pdf describing the device)](http://tf.nist.gov/timefreq/general/pdf/2309.pdf)  at NIST.

Building upon Ben Crowell's comment, a balance scale will measure the gravitational force on an object while keeping $\Delta l$ arbitrarily small (the more accurate your measurement of the scale's tilt, the less the masses move during the measurement).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Nevertheless, a spin is not a classical variable. I was explicitly asking for a classical measure. The Zeeman splitting is not eligible as such :-). As for the balance, I'm always wondering if equilibrium  is a measure of force. I have to think about that. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't agree that the electron measurement is not classical. The measurement relies on the magnetic moment of the electron which is a classical quantity in the same way the charge of the electron is. The quantum mechanical effects are in the quantization of the projection which produces the discrete energy splitting in the magnetic field. Even if the projection were not quantized, a Stern-Gerlach apparatus would show a spread of electron positions due to the interaction of the magnetic moment with the B field gradient (instead of just two distinct locations).

Comment: I understand your frustration, but a Stern-Gerlach apparatus integrate the magnetic field gradient along a trajectory. It is definitely not a measure of $B$. So, measuring the charge or the associated magnetic momentum is a classical measure which indeed records a flux or a work.

Comment: Not frustrated, just trying to understand :-). On a pedantic side note, all measurements require some indicator. This implies a change between two or more discrete states with potential barriers separating the states. Always some work involved in making the change.

Answer (score 2):

Measure the Lorentz force acting on a moving point charge, e.g. electron in a Penning trap or cyclotron resonance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you please consider expanding a bit. It's true that a measure of $F=q\left(E+v\times B\right)$ is a measure of a force (and at the same time of the field, not of the flux), but I do not understand how you measure it. Could you please give us a setup ? Or a reference of course. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The [Lorentz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hendrik_Lorentz) credited for the [force law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force) (among other things) has a "t".  You may be confusing him with the [Lorenz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludvig_Lorenz) who is best known for his [gauge condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_gauge_condition).  Or maybe that was just a typo.  :)

Answer (score 2):

A compass is a classical magnetic field measurement.  It's nontrivial to get the magnitude from a compass but the direction is certainly easy.  But if you read Feyman you'll see that it is impossible to explain magnetism classically.  Our models of electrons in teeny Amperian loops is bogus.  In fact the famous Bohr–van Leeuwen theorem shows that classical magnetic fields are impossible.  So magnetism is fundamentally a quantum mechanical phenomenon.

And here's a nit to pick with some of the answers.  Almost no measurement is direct.  A bathroom scale does **NOT** measure force.  If it has a spring, it measures displacement and converts that to force via Hooke's law. Thus you're assuming you know the spring constant and that the spring is kept in it's linear regime.  If it's a strain gage device it doesn't even directly measure strain directly.  It measure tiny changes in resistance using a Wheatstone bridge and converts these to strain and thence to "weight." Almost every measurement you can think of is actually an **inference** of what you want from what you can really measure.

Answer (score 1):

If the magnetic field from the solenoid is strong enough you might be able to place a physical magnet on a sensitive force meter to provide a reading from which the strength of the magnetic field could be calculated. I have never heard of it being done except in relatively simple situations. The [force between bar magnets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_between_magnets#Magnetic_force_due_to_non-uniform_magnetic_field) is the calculation that would be necessary to carry out. The setup would entail treating the solenoid as one of the two magnets. This may or may not be possible. I have no experience doing this. I am merely pontificating like a dilettante.

This was meant more as a comment than an answer, but considering the large number of comments I desired to keep it from getting lost in the discussion.

> Say differently, one wants to know how to interpret a classical measure: is it (always ?) an integral or can it -- under specific conditions -- give a local value ?

Unless you are willing to infer a local value from the trajectory of an electron as Jason mentioned, or from the same bending of electrons in the hall effect sensors, then there is always going to be some area involved. However if area/flux is the issue to avoid then you could always try the [Gilbert model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_between_magnets#Gilbert_Model), which Griffiths recommends against using for any quantitative work.

Comment: @JoelHobbit Thanks a lot for your answer. Would you please elaborate a little bit more it ? As far as I understand, you answer saying "Measuring a force can be done with a force meter..." Can you give us a setup, or a reference about what you call a "sensitive force meter" ? Also, I believe the force on a magnet is related to the flux on its surface, isn't it ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @JoelHobbit Thanks a lot for your update. I nevertheless believe this is still not a measure of a force (or the magnetic field), since you need to provide a way to measure it. I continue to believe you need to measure the work of the Lorentz force. Note that the Lorentz force is recovered from the Faraday law, which is a law describing electromagnetic fluxes, not field. See this answer for more details http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/67626/16689 . Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Have you seen TH Boyer's interpretation of the [Aharonov-Bohm](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.205.6817&rep=rep1&type=pdf) effect?

Comment: @JoelHobbit I think I've read them long ago, but I never really understood what he tried to do. There is also this discussion http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/56926/16689 associated with some paper by Vaidman I still do not understand. By the way, I think I have to change the title of this question, because it is not really related to the AB effect. It's more about wether or not can we measure a field, or are we stuck with flux . Thanks for your comment.

Comment: The frequency of oscillation of a compass needle depends on the strength of the field.

Answer (score -1):

A small rotating loop can measure B,  small rotating short dipole can measure E.  A to my knowledge, has never been measured. Remarkably the secondary winding of an iron cored transformer operates in an area devoid of B field but there is significant A.  The AB effect is not proved by the the famous Tonomura experiment.  There are peer reviewed articles critical of this experiment.  One of the papers is titled:***Is the Static Magnetic Vector Potential Screened by a Thick Superconducting Shield***

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123702/discussion-on-answer-by-barry-can-we-measure-an-electromagnetic-field).

Comment: Please take further comments to the chat room. That's what it's there for.