# How to incorporate Dirac's magnetic monopole solution into a continuous magnetic charge density?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-monopoles, dirac-monopole, dirac-string

Dirac famously solved Maxwell equations in the presence of a **point** magnetic monopole. He was able to do so in a manner which used only the standard vector potential $\vec{A}$ and gave the correct monopole field $\vec{B}$ outside the monopole. What he effectively did was to consider the monopole to be one end of a very thin, semi-infinite solenoid which, by some clever mathematics of gauge transformation, remains invisible in all observables.

My question: is the Dirac solution specific to pointlike monopoles or is it possible to produce a continuous magnetic charge distribution using his method by superposition?

If Dirac solution is specific to pointlike monopoles, is there another way to describe a continuous magnetic charge distribution via vector potential $\vec{A}$? For example, what $\vec{A}$ corresponds to a uniformly charged magnetic ball of radius $R$ and magnetic charge $g$?

If one can extend Dirac solution to an arbitrary magnetic charge distribution, what happens to the invisible solenoids/strings? Do they behave nicely or do they entangle in some complicated way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to model continuous magnetic charge densities via Dirac monopoles. Dirac argument *necessarily* quantizes the allowed magnetic charges, and, crucially, at the position of the monopole, the vector potential $A$ is not defined.

The condition that the magnetic four-current vanishes is essentially the necessary condition for the vector potential $A$ to exist in the first place, see e.g. [this answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/319434/50583). See also [this answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/261261/50583) for other options to "add" magnetic charges to standard electromagnetism.