# Magnetic monopole Lagrangian and Hamiltonian

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-monopoles

How do I find an equation analogous to
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}(q,\dot q)=\frac12 m \dot q ^2-q\phi+q\vec{\dot q}\cdot \vec A\quad\quad \text{where}\quad \vec B =\vec\nabla\times\vec A, \quad \vec E=-\vec\nabla\phi-\partial_t\vec A
\end{equation}
for magnetic monopole instead of the electric point charge coupling to the $A$-field?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/343075/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/59874/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/261257/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/164182/2451 and links therein.

Comment: See the Seiberg-Witten equation on Wikipedia.