# Force law from Lagrangian for magnetic monopole

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, magnetic-fields, action, magnetic-monopoles

How to construct a Lagrangian that gives the Lorentz force law with both magnetic and electric monopole?

I got that the force will be of the form

\begin{equation}
m \frac{\mathrm{d}x^\nu}{\mathrm{d}\tau^2}=\left(qF^{\mu\nu}+ g\star F^{\mu\nu}\right)\frac{\mathrm{d}x_\nu}{\mathrm{d}\tau}
\end{equation}
where $\star$ is the Hodge dual, but I am not sure what kind of Lagrangian gives the magnetic part.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/343075/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/59874/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/261257/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/164182/2451 and links therein.