# Why the integral of Berry curvature over a closed surface is not zero?

Tags: gauss-law, berry-pancharatnam-phase

I read [[1](https://phy.ntnu.edu.tw/~changmc/Paper/Berry_IFF_FF_4.pdf),[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry_connection_and_curvature)] that for a spin-1/2 particle under magnetic field, the Berry curvature is a monopole,
$$
\mathbf F_{\pm} = \mp\frac{\mathbf B}{2B^3},
$$
of which the integral over a closed surface is $2\pi$.

Because the Berry curvature is defined by the curl of Berry connection $\mathbf F = \nabla_B\times\mathbf A$, the divergence of a curl $\mathbf A\Rightarrow\nabla_B\cdot \mathbf F =0$ must be zero, and so is the aforementioned integral
$$
\oint_{S_B}\mathbf F\cdot d\mathbf S_B=\int_{V_B}\nabla_B\cdot\mathbf F =0.
$$

Is there anything missing here?

**Edit:** Both daniel and Sebastian answer my problem. Another [discussion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/326504/this-vector-potential-gives-a-magnetic-monopole-field-whats-wrong-with-it) is also helpful to me.

Comment: Hint: Remember what you learnt about point charges.

Comment: @SebastianRiese Well, I learned that the point-charge solution in electromagnetism can be expressed as the *divergence* of a scalar potential, but never as the *curl* of a vector potential. But this rule seems to fail here. I edited my problem for clarity.

Comment: Note (from Wikipedia) that the divergence theorem applies to continuously differentiable functions, i.e. functions whose derivative is continuous. Is ∂F continuous in your integration region?

Comment: Also, the relation $\vec F = \nabla \times A$ breaks down at $B = 0$ (it only holds in the non-degenerate)

Comment: (.. case). My hint was supposed to mean, that $\nabla \cdot \vec F \propto \delta(\vec B)$, since the field is the same as that of a point charge. And $\nabla \cdot (\nabla \times \vec A) = 0$ simply does not hold in general at a singularity.

Comment: @SebastianRiese Thanks so much for clearing it up. As you said, the $B=0$ origin should be excluded here.